# Error: expression must have arithmetic, unscoped enum, or pointer type with operator overload

Tags: c++

I overload prefix and postfix increment and decrement operators. I am able to call them, and they work just fine in assignment operations and just 'by themselves'.
However, I can't call a member function from objects used with such *prefixed* operators. Everything works well with postfix notation though.
The compiler gives me 2 errors:

- expression must have arithmetic, unscoped enum, or pointer type
- '++'/'--' needs l-value

I can't understand why it is so.

Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; //I know I shouldn't do this in real projects
class Time
{
public:
    Time() : hrs(0), mins(0), secs(0) {};
    Time(int m_hrs, int m_mins, int m_secs) : hrs(m_hrs), mins(m_mins), secs(m_secs) {};
    void display()
    {
        cout << hrs << ':' << mins << ':' << secs;
    } const 
    Time operator+(Time time) const
    {
        int tmp_hrs = hrs + time.hrs;
        int tmp_mins = mins + time.mins;
        int tmp_secs = secs + time.secs;
        if (tmp_secs >= 60)
        {
            tmp_secs -= 60;
            tmp_mins++;
        }
        if (tmp_mins >= 60)
        {
            tmp_mins -= 60;
            tmp_hrs++;
        }
        if (tmp_hrs >= 24)
        {
            tmp_hrs -= 24;
        }
        return { tmp_hrs, tmp_mins, tmp_secs };
    }
    Time operator++()
    {
        Time tmp(hrs, mins, secs);
        tmp.secs++;
        tmp.resolve_overflow();
        hrs = tmp.hrs;
        mins = tmp.mins;
        secs = tmp.secs;
        return tmp;
    }
    Time operator++(int)
    {
        Time to_return(hrs, mins, secs);
        Time tmp(hrs, mins, secs);
        tmp.secs++;
        tmp.resolve_overflow();
        hrs = tmp.hrs;
        mins = tmp.mins;
        secs = tmp.secs;
        return to_return;
    }
    Time operator--()
    {
        Time tmp(hrs, mins, secs);
        tmp.secs--;
        tmp.resolve_underflow();
        hrs = tmp.hrs;
        mins = tmp.mins;
        secs = tmp.secs;
        return tmp;
    }
    Time operator--(int)
    {
        Time to_return(hrs, mins, secs);
        Time tmp(hrs, mins, secs);
        tmp.secs--;
        tmp.resolve_underflow();
        hrs = tmp.hrs;
        mins = tmp.mins;
        secs = tmp.secs;
        return to_return;
    }

private:
    int hrs;
    int mins;
    int secs;
void resolve_overflow()
{
    if (secs >= 60)
    {
        secs -= 60;
        mins++;
    }
    if (mins >= 60)
    {
        mins -= 60;
        hrs++;
    }
    if (hrs >= 24)
    {
        hrs -= 24;
    }
}
void resolve_underflow()
{
    if (secs < 0)
    {
        secs = 59;
        mins--;
    }
    if (mins < 0)
    {
        mins = 59;
        hrs--;
    }
    if (hrs < 0)
    {
        hrs = 23;
    }
}
};


int main()
{
    Time t1(0,0,0);
    ++t1.display(); cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the method you are calling as an Rvalue is type 'void' and will not generate a value to stand on the Rside of the (pre-increment) operator

Comment: Recommended reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: haven't gone through all the code but prefix operator is an rvalue `(++t1).display(); cout << endl;` should make that an lvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to increment void, which is the return type of display().

This makes clear that ++ is directed at the object.

```
int main()
{
    Time t1(0,0,0);
    (++t1).display(); cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I am not sure why you're creating a random object for the prefix operator++. Why not return the same object by reference like the fundamental types?

```
    Time& operator++()
{
    this->secs++;
    resolve_overflow();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. As for returning a random object, you are most definitely right here. I thought of it myself. My book hasn't introduced the concept of pointers yet, so this must be the reason it hasn't explained how to return self from member functions yet.